# handleInterval in NestJS not working with mongoose

Tags: nestjs

My goal is to build a nest.js app using cronjobs to access the mongoDB each 10 seconds. In this case I want to read from mongo but in the future I was also thinking of saving to mongo.

I have no errors but the cron job is not executing

The project is here:
https://github.com/meyetchristian4/nestJS-with-mongo-and-taskScheduler

Answer (score 0):

### AppModule

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    TaskModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/nest'),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You haven't imported the `ScheduleModule` and initialised the listeners, so although the `TasksModule` is registered, the listeners are only registered as plain methods.

### TasksService

**Optional**

To enable you to obtain the `allData` as I believe you wanted (you had it commented out), you can change your method:

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(TasksService.name);

  constructor(@InjectModel(info.name) private infoModel: Model) {}

  @Interval(10000)
  async handleInterval() {
    this.logger.debug('Called every 10 seconds');
    let allData = await this.findAll();
    console.log(`Mongo: ${allData}`); // or JSON.stringify(allData)
  }

  async findAll(): Promise {
    return this.infoModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[Nest] 11320   - 24/05/2021, 17:21:44   [TasksService] Called every 10 seconds
```

### Learn More

1. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#installation